# How to get (not found) results when search with (whereIn)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I got this table in my Laravel Project DB scheme:

```
id | user_id | reference | created_at
---------------------------------------
1  |   2     | ref - 1   | dd/mm/yy
2  |   2     | ref - 2   | dd/mm/yy
3  |   2     | ref - 3   | dd/mm/yy
4  |   2     | ref - 4   | dd/mm/yy
```

Now, I want to build a query to pass an array of references, then I get the results in return for each element in the array I did pass, such like this:

```
id  | user_id | reference | created_at
--------------------------------------
3   |   2     | ref - 3   | dd/mm/yy
4   |   2     | ref - 4   | dd/mm/yy
null|  null   | ref - 5   | null
```

Where **ref - 5** is not found

Update:
for now this is the code I have:

```
$references = ['ref - 3','ref - 4','ref - 5'];
$result = Reference::whereIn('reference',$references)->get();
```

the result is ignoring **ref - 5** as it is not found.
so what I get is like:

```
id  | user_id | reference | created_at
--------------------------------------
3   |   2     | ref - 3   | dd/mm/yy
4   |   2     | ref - 4   | dd/mm/yy
```

I want to preserve a row for not found references, so results become like the following:

```
id  | user_id | reference | created_at
--------------------------------------
3   |   2     | ref - 3   | dd/mm/yy
4   |   2     | ref - 4   | dd/mm/yy
null|  null   | ref - 5   | null
```

with less number of steps, is there any way to fetch such a result just by building a query?

Comment: Can you add examples of what you get and what you expect?

Comment: @vivek_23 sure, updated the question

Comment: It doesn't seem that this functionality would be by default, but you can play with https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-collections#custom-collections custom collections

Comment: @AhmedNasr You will have to do this using PHP itself since there is no way to attach non matched values using SQL unless you would like to create [views](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/views.html)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to achieve this using PHP. It will be readable as well.

```
<?php

$references = ['ref - 3','ref - 4','ref - 5'];
$result = Reference::whereIn('reference',$references)->get()->toArray();
$obtained_refs = [];

foreach($result as $each_record){
    $obtained_refs[$each_record['reference']] = true;
}

foreach($references as $each_ref){
    if(!isset($obtained_refs[$each_ref])){
        // if reference is not present, add it to result array
        $result[] = [
            'id' => NULL,
            'user_id' => NULL,
            'reference' => $each_ref,
            'created_at' => NULL
        ];
    }
}
```

**Algorithm:**

- First get the result set from the DB and store it in `$result`(like you already did).
- Now, make a new array, let's say `$obtained_refs` which will keep track of all references you got in the result set, by making each ref as it's key. This is done to make the lookup faster.
- Now, loop over `$references` array and check to see if any ref is **not** present in our `$obtained_refs`. If yes, add it to `$result` array, else don't take any action.
- Thus, `$result` array will contain your desired result in the end.

Comment: thanks for your time, sure this is doable but keep in mind that I simplified this example as much as possible, in real scenario  I got more data to fetch with eager loading related tables. That's why I was seeking for cleaner way to achieve this.

Comment: @AhmedNasr ok, but why would you want to show refs that aren't in the DB?

Comment: because the user would input 100 references to check on, he needs to be able to tell which is found and which isn't in his final result.

Comment: sure it does, I upvoted your answer but I'll wait maybe anyone has what I'm asking for, thank you again for help.

Comment: @AhmedNasr Sure, no issues.